# Creating dynamic array in class [python]

Tags: python, arrays

I've written my own `List` class that wraps another `list`-like array type. The array has a fixed capacity and when the array is full I want the capacity to double automatically. For example, if my base capacity is 5 then when the array is full and another item is added, it doubles the capacity to 10 before adding the item.

Here's my code:

```
from referential_array import build_array

class List:

    def __init__(self,capacity):
        assert capacity >0, "Capacity cannot be negative"
        self.count = 0
        self._array = build_array(capacity)
        self.capacity = capacity

    def append(self,item):
        has_space_left = not self.is_full()
        if has_space_left:
            self._array[self.count] = item
            self.count+=1
        else:                                      #Issue here
            create_more_space = List.__init__(self,capacity*2) #if list is full, capacity *2
            self.count+=1

if __name__== "__main__":
    myList = List(6)
    myList.append(4)
    myList.append(7)
    myList.append(1)
    myList.append(3)
    myList.append(2)
    myList.append(17)
    myList.append(18)
    myList.append(20)
```

below, first i specify the size is 6. Then i go ahead an append more than 6 items. by right, when python sees that there is no longer any space, the capacity will be doubled and hence 18 and 20 can be appended as well.

I'm getting an error saying capacity is not defined at the append function. The output I'm trying to get is:

```
4
7
1
3
2
17
18
20
```

Comment: use `self.capacity`, not `capacity` alone. But I feel there are other problems in your code just looking at it...

Comment: It is not defined because you must access `capacity` through `self.capacity`. Also, what you're trying to do will overwrite `_array` with everything you've appended in it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because members of an object in Python *must* be accessed from the `self` reference:

```
create_more_space = List.__init__(self, self.capacity * 2)
```

I'm not sure why you're doing this since the built-in python `list` type has this functionality, so I'll assume this is for learning. In which case, I suggest pulling the resizing out into a separate method that can be called from the constructor and `append`. Also, your current set up will lose the contents of the array when the capacity changes (because you'll be assigning a new array over the top of the old one). e.g.

```
new_array = build_array(capacity)
new_array[0:len(self._array)] = self._array
self._array = new_array
```

Comment: yes, i understand that the set up will lose contents of the old array. Do i have to create a new function for this instead? If so, how would i ensure the array isn't overwriting the old contents?

Comment: It's hard to say how to copy the contents since we don't know what `referential_array.build_array` is. If it acts like a regular python list, you could use a list slice (answer updated)