# Creating my own python list (dynamic array) in class

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic

I may have the exact same question as here:
[Creating dynamic array in class [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166225/creating-dynamic-array-in-class-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)
but I have more info that post's helpers asked for:

referential_array consists of:
import ctypes

```
def build_array(size):

    if size <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Array size should be larger than 0.")
    if not isinstance(size,  int):
        raise ValueError("Array size should be an integer.")
    array = (size * ctypes.py_object)()
    array[:] = size * [None]
    return array
```

My attempts at resizing:

from referential_array import build_array

```
class Array:

    def __init__(self, size):
        assert size >= 0, "size must be positive"
        self.the_array = build_array(size)
        self.count = 0
        self.size = size


def resize(self):

    if self.isFull():
        self.the_array2 = build_array(self.size*2)
        for i in range(len(self)):
            self.the_array2.append(self[i])
        self.the_array = self.the_array2
        self.size = (self.size)*2    
    elif len(self) < (1/8)*(self.size) and (self.size) >= 40:
        self.the_array2 = build_array((self.size)//2)
        for i in range(len(self)):
            self.the_array2.append(self[i])
        self.the_array = self.the_array2
        self.size = (self.size)//2
    else:
        pass

def __str__(self):
    result = ""
    for i in range(self.count):
        result += str(self.the_array[i])
        result += "\n"
    return result

def __len__(self):
    return self.count

def isEmpty(self):
    return len(self) == 0

def isFull(self):
    return len(self) >= len(self.the_array)

def indexValid(self,index):
    return -len(self) <= index and index < len(self)

def __getitem__(self,index):
    if self.indexValid(index):
        if index >= 0:
            return self.the_array[index]
        else:
            return self.the_array[index+len(self)]
    else:
        raise IndexError("index out of range")


def __setitem__(self,index,item):
    if self.indexValid(index):
        if index >= 0:
            self.the_array[index] = item
        else:
            self.the_array[index+len(self)] = item
    else:
        raise IndexError("index out of range")
def append(self,item):

    if not self.isFull():
        self.the_array[self.count] = item
        self.count += 1

    self.resize()
```

The above code gave an "AttributeError: 'py_object_Array_40' object has no attribute 'append'"

Attempt two at using [:] :

```
def resize(self):

    if self.isFull:
        self.the_array2 = build_array(self.size*2)
        self.the_array2 = self.the_array[:]
        self.the_array = self.the_array2
        self.size = (self.size)*2    
    elif len(self) < (1/8)*(self.size) and (self.size) >= 40:
        self.the_array2 = build_array((self.size)//2)
        self.the_array2 = self.the_array[:]
        self.the_array = self.the_array2
        self.size = (self.size)//2
    else:
        pass
```

This time I get a memoryerror.
Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: What do you mean under `if self.isFull:` in `def resize()`. You don't call `self.isFull`, you might need to correct it to  `if self.isFull():`

Comment: I've tried both, originally starting at size 20, back when the resize method was still under the init method taking the brackets away seemed to have made it work one iteration up to resizing to size 40, but during that time, if the array was then appended to 40 elements from 20 it didn't resize again.

Comment: Do you understand that `if self.is Full:` is completely incorrect statement?

Comment: Ok I'll try that once power is back, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: >> "power is back" What do you mean?

Comment: Power outage at my place now I'm using phone to reply, don't have the files on laptop either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154392/discussion-between-kenshin-and-redeyed).

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but are you sure your code is well indented? All your methods definitions should be indented like this:

```
class Array:

    def __init__(self, size):
        assert size >= 0, "size must be positive"
        self.the_array = build_array(size)
        self.count = 0
        self.size = size


    def resize(self):

        if self.isFull:
            self.the_array2 = build_array(self.size*2)
            for i in range(len(self)):
                self.the_array2.append(self[i])
            self.the_array = self.the_array2
            self.size = (self.size)*2    
        elif len(self) < (1/8)*(self.size) and (self.size) >= 40:
            self.the_array2 = build_array((self.size)//2)
            for i in range(len(self)):
                self.the_array2.append(self[i])
            self.the_array = self.the_array2
            self.size = (self.size)//2
        else:
            pass
```

If you don't indent correctly, the append method is seen as a function proper to your Python module, instead of as a class method - which could explain your first error message.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the code is well indented or not on his end. That doesn't explain the second error, but at least it could be a source of error for his first error message.

Comment: Sorry, the code is properly indented on my end, just when I was posting this it pasted wrongly. My place just got a blackout so I will reply with phone or tommorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def resize(self):

    if self.isFull: # Fix it to self.isFull()
        self.the_array2 = build_array(self.size*2)
        self.the_array2 = self.the_array[:]
        self.the_array = self.the_array2
        self.size = (self.size)*2    
    elif len(self) < (1/8)*(self.size) and (self.size) >= 40:
        self.the_array2 = build_array((self.size)//2)
        self.the_array2 = self.the_array[:]
        self.the_array = self.the_array2
        self.size = (self.size)//2
    else:
        pass
```

Fix `self.isFull` to `self.isFull`**()** Because you'll never enter to other conditions.

Comment: I've changed it to if self.isFull(): Still got the same error